# cmd := exec.Command("ssh", "ec2-user@publicip") exits with Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: go, ssh

I'm using org/x/crypto/ssh package to build a cli application to ssh through bastion to a server using ssh certs. Basic workflow is;
cli tool gets the users public key  and get it signed from vault ssh ca, and that resulting cert is used to authenticate the user to the servers.
It worked fine.

```
configure := &ssh.ClientConfig{
            User: "ec2-user",
            Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
                // Use the PublicKeys method for remote authentication.
                ssh.PublicKeys(certSigner),
            },
            HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
        }
        //log.Println(config.bastionserver.publicIP)

        // Connect to the remote server and perform the SSH handshake.
        proxyClient, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", net.JoinHostPort(config.bastion.publicIP, "22"), configure)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }

        session, err := proxyClient.NewSession()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        defer session.Close()

        if err = session.Shell(); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }

        session.Wait()
```

I made some changes and reverted back to the code and I started getting the following error. I used git to revert.

> ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [publickey none], no supported methods remain

So I reduced the complexity and tried the following block to try to connect just to the bastion through the cli app I'm building.

```
cmd := exec.Command("ssh", "-i", signedKeyPath, "-i", privateKeyPath, "ec2-user@host")

    fmt.Println(cmd.String())
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
```

still it exits with

> /usr/bin/ssh -i /home/rochana/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub -i /home/rochana/.ssh/id_rsa ec2-user@host
>   ec2-user@host: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
>   2020-02-17 11:01:25.168548 I | exit status 255.

I tried compiling and running it on a different PC and I get the same results. I tried saving the cert to disk and giving the path.

but if I run the same command on terminal. It works fine and connects to the instance.

> ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ec2-user@host

or just copy and paste cmd.String() output

> /usr/bin/ssh -i /home/rochana/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub -i /home/rochana/.ssh/id_rsa ec2-user@host

everything works fine when I run directly on terminal but not with exec command

Comment: You don’t need to provide the .pub file, so you can omit the first ‘-i’ argument. Does it make a difference if you use ‘-l’, ‘ec2-user’ as arguments? (As opposed to ‘ec2-user@host’)

Comment: i just tried what you suggested, but i still get  the same error. what confuses me is all the commands  works fine on the terminal but not in the code.

Comment: Permission denied sounds like there is a file which you don't have enough permissions to read/execute.  Are you running the go program as the same user as your shell?  I can't see what is in `signedKeyPath` - are you sure it is the same file name that you pass to ssh directly? (It should really have a file extension of .key or something.)  You could try changing the perms +rx on all the files.  Also you could try using absolute path names to make sure you are finding the right files.

Comment: @Andrew **/usr/bin/ssh -i /home/rochana/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub -i /home/rochana/.ssh/id_rsa ec2-user@host** this is the output of the cmd.String() yes I'm using absolute paths. if just copy and paste the above command on terminal, it works.  `err = ioutil.WriteFile(expandPath("~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub"), []byte(signedKey), 0644)`  this is the how i save the signed cert file. i even tried 0777

Comment: This worked for me with the command ``cmd := exec.Command("ssh", "-i", privateKeyPath, "-vv", "user@address")```. Note I added ``-vv``to provide some diagnostic info because my first attempt failed. The issue turned out to be a space in front of the username; this got me thinking so I added a space to the start of the certificate filename and got ```Permission denied (publickey)``` (copying that command to the console would have worked). So check for any stray spaces and see if the info provided by ```-v``` helps.

Comment: authenticating with the private key works but not the ssh certificate.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned above, it will not work with the public key. The public key is for the server side, the private key is for the client. You should remove the public portion from your command.

Comment: yup i tried that also. could there be some other reason. I'm asking this because my implementation with **org/x/crypto/ssh** worked well before. Once I got the certificate signed I could use **func (c *Client) NewSession() (*Session, error)** and **func (s *Session) Shell() error** to start an interactive session. But now even that code doesn't work.

Comment: looks like the issue is when I use variables as flags in the command. Even with the org/x/crypto/ssh implementation I got the same problem. Doesn't make any sense!

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to, Vault server not being able to sync up its time.

Comment: is the time correct on both server and certificate generating machines?